# On real mobile device, landscape view does not support in buildfire mobile app

Tags: buildfire

Can we add plugin Rotate features in Buildfire mobile app..?

Right now buildfire mobile app showing in vertical mobile app, landscape / page rotating feature is not enabled.

Is it available this features or not..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there may be plans to change it in the future, but currently I don't believe it supports landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where it only makes sense to be landscape. You could rotate your plugin using CSS. Theoretically you could read the orientation of the device using html5 to trigger auto-rotation using CSS